# DC offset for AC signal

Tags: ac, voltage-divider, dc-offset

[image]

Hi guys, I am looking for some clarification regarding how to create a DC offset for an AC signal. Attached to this post is a quick schematic that I have drawn. Am I correct in saying that by connecting the red/pink lead to the middle of my voltage divider and the ground of the signal to the ground of the voltage divider, that my AC signal (say 1Vpp) will reach a maximum of 2.15V and a minimum of 1.15V?

Comment: Yes, if you AC coupled the red lean to the potential divider by a suitable capacitor.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask what role the capacitor will play here then?

Comment: It blocks DC voltage.

Comment: Given the 100K resistors in the divider;  a blocking capacitor having a value of at least 1mF / f seems like a reasonable choice.  So at least 1uF for 1kHz, 0.1uF for 10kHz, etc.

Comment: Function generators output DC coupled signal. The DC offset is 0V by default. You can skip the circuitry and just set the function generator DC offset to be 1.65V. Unless you want to do something more that just connect a function generator which you don't mention.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to create a DC offset for a function generator would be an op amp acting as a differential amplifier, in the normal 4 resistor 1 op amp style, the function generator output would be the inputs to the differential amp with 1 small change

[image]

the ground for the resistor on the + input, you would instead connect to the output of a second op amp to buffer what ever voltage you want to offset it by,

Comment: The usual way to add DC offset to signal generator output is to just use the DC offset control on the signal generator. Depends of course if that is enough or if there are other requirements.