# What is the procedure of giving sine wave as adc inputs to microcontrollers

Tags: adc

Hi iam just trying to find adc values by giving a sine wave as a input to adc pin of microcontroller atsaml10 series with the peak to peak of 6V and frequency of 10Hz and adc sampling rate is 1khz and iam unable to get proper values.

Comment: What's your schematic? Layout? Datasheet? Code? What is the output you see?

Answer (score 1):

It is not mentioned if the signal has a DC offset I am assuming your signal has a peak voltage of +3Vp and -3Vp.

[image]

First scale the signal down to the appropriate voltage levels for your MCU 3Vpp (+1.5Vp to -1.5Vp).

[image]

Since the MCU will not measure a negative voltage since Vref is biased to ground and and V+ source. 3.3V - 0V. It is required to apply a DC offset to the signal. 1.5Vdc offset.

[image]

This should give the appropriate readings.

This is a very crude but cheap implementation to create a DC offset. You would be better off using a opamp like this [DC offset for AC signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493538/dc-offset-for-ac-signal) with a negative gain.

Please note the component values are only for example purposes. The resistor dividers should have a ratio of 0.5. The capacitor value should selected for the frequency to minimize its reactance to reduce signal attenuation. 100uF looks to be suitable for 10Hz 159.15 ohm.

[Calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/capacitor-impedance-calculator/)

Comment: The values in your 3rd circuit don't work for 10 Hz. The impedance of 100 nF is around 160 kohm and the resistive divider has an impedance of 500 ohm. So there is not much left of the AC amplitide at the ADC input.

Answer (score 0):

The MCU does not support signal voltages beyond supply rails, so feeding in a 6Vpp signal into a MCU powered (maybe) by 3.3V supply cannot measure it properly.

It may even damage the MCU permanently so it is possible that MCU cannot measure anything properly if it is damaged.

Comment: What may be the ideal peak to peak to check the values. Atsaml takes maximum of 3.3v

Comment: As I tried by giving a on board 3.3v iam getting a proper values as 4095 as resolution of my adc is 12 bit